# Highcharts x-axis offset but restored after resized

Tags: javascript, highcharts, offset

In the latest version of Highcharts, my x-axis line is larger than expected is offset. But, if I open Firebug (who re-sizes my page) and close it, my x-axis is in his right place.

Before opening Firebug:[here](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg51/scaled.php?server=51&filename=60679484.jpg&res=landing)

After:[here](http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/533/65999168.jpg)

Here is the code:

```
options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        animation: false,
        renderTo: 'chart1'

    },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['STBL','AHM OE','TCR'],
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                overflow: "justify",
                align: 'right',
                y: 20
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false,

        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return ''+
                    this.x +': '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 5);
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                pointWidth: 8
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: '',
            data: [9.93782224348591E-4,0.0012882708991709339,0.01952599999881562]
        }]
    };
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Could someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Your code seems to work correct here,
@ http://jsfiddle.net/qSERx/

Comment: Probably something's wrong with your css.

Comment: What plugins are you using ? Where do you open it ?

Comment: I use jquery ui tabs but, if I put my chart out from a tab, it does not work anyway.

Comment: I tried to remove all my css sheets, but it is the same.